# How can I get a program working with missing references?

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2015, office-interop, dao

I've got the code for project written with a vb.net, .net Framework 2.0, Windows Form Application.  I'm trying to get it working in Visual Studio 2015.  When I open it up, I'm missing several references.  I try to compile (Clean/Rebuild) it, and get multiple errors.  I've looked up the files online, but all I can find are sites saying I need to reinstall them.  I don't have the dll's and don't have any idea what these do (except that they vaguely are Microsoft related).  Can someone tell me how to get the program working or how to find the files?

Here are the missing references:

AxInterop.MSDataGridLib

AxMSDataGridLib

DAO

Interop.MSDataGridLib

Microsoft.ReportVeiwer.WinForms

Microsoft.Vbe.Interop

MSDataGridLib

MSDataReportLib

MSDATASRC

Here is the error I get when I rebuild the solution:

1>------ Rebuild All started: Project: RTS, Configuration: Release Any CPU ------
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1819,5): warning MSB3245: Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "AxInterop.MSDataGridLib". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors.
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1819,5): warning MSB3245: Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "Interop.MSDataGridLib". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors.
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2398,5): warning MSB3284: Cannot get the file path for type library "cde57a40-8b86-11d0-b3c6-00a0c90aea82" version 1.0. Library not registered. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8002801D (TYPE_E_LIBNOTREGISTERED))
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2398,5): warning MSB3284: Cannot get the file path for type library "00025e01-0000-0000-c000-000000000046" version 4.0. Library not registered. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8002801D (TYPE_E_LIBNOTREGISTERED))
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2398,5): warning MSB3284: Cannot get the file path for type library "cde57a40-8b86-11d0-b3c6-00a0c90aea82" version 1.0. Library not registered. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8002801D (TYPE_E_LIBNOTREGISTERED))
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2398,5): warning MSB3284: Cannot get the file path for type library "642ac760-aab4-11d0-8494-00a0c90dc8a9" version 1.0. Library not registered. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8002801D (TYPE_E_LIBNOTREGISTERED))
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2398,5): warning MSB3283: Cannot find wrapper assembly for type library "MSDATASRC". Verify that (1) the COM component is registered correctly and (2) your target platform is the same as the bitness of the COM component. For example, if the COM component is 32-bit, your target platform must not be 64-bit.
========== Rebuild All: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========

Here is the image showing broken references:

[image]

Comment: Did you even google [this](https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+fix+axinterop.msdatagridlib+missing+dll)? There's all kinds of info out there on replacing those dlls

Answer (score 0):

Probably this old project resulted from poorly converting a yet older (non-.NET) Visual Basic or VBA application to .NET. E.g. DAO is a database access technology used in these old languages. You should replace it by ADO.NET which is integrated into the .NET Framework.

The same is probably true for most of the other referenced DLLs. To be able to do this, you must understand what the old components did.

However, my estimation is that the whole application needs to be rewritten from scratch.

Comment: Unfortunately, rewriting it is not an option.  My boss wants me to make changes to this program in Visual Studio at a client site.  Any suggestions on where to find these files?

Answer (score 0):

You will need the Microsoft Office Primary Interop Assemblies for Interop with MS Office. Which package depends on the version of Office you are running: [Microsoft Office PIA Website](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/15s06t57.aspx)